# Cannot navigate through the site if a file is being downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse, outputstream

I am trying to download a large file (stored in the database) from a server by chunks using `Context.Response.OutputStream.Write` method. But I cannot navigate through the site till download completion, in other words till response ending. There is a link on the page which just redirects to the generic handler (*.ashx file type).
Using `Context.Response.OutputStream.TransmiteFile` is not suitable. Also downloading in the other thread is not fix the issue.

```
HttpResponse response = Context.Response;
Int32 chunkSize = AppSettings.DownloadChunkSizeMb * 1024 * 1024;
Int32 filePosition = 0;

// Here some code to fill response headers...

while (filePosition < Metadata.Size) // Metadata is retrieved from the database
{
    Byte[] chunk = // Retrieving file chunk from the database...

    if (!response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        break;
    }
    response.OutputStream.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
    response.Flush();

    filePosition += chunk.Length;
}
```

Comment: multi-thread it! just do the download on another thread, this should fix your issue.

Comment: @theWongfonSemicolon, thanks for your comment, but I have tried to do this asynchronously and the page still waited for response.

Comment: Or in some solutions redirects to a white page and nothing happens.

Comment: Threads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The client-side is waiting for response ending, so what the difference if we run a new thread on the server-side? There is no difference, because client-side will still wait for response ending, but now from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

THis is a tricky question. Let me know if I got his right
First thing that came to my mind was an async ajax call. An async ajax call would not block the browser, and the actions would be performed on the server side.

If you need to navigate through the pages, you would need this ajax to be in a different window or a different tab (I have done this with a different window.)
You can open a new window, make an async ajax call, and close that window as the response from server side arrives.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to do this.